# How to set center for geojson layer in leaftet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I added geojson Layer in leaflet.But I want to know can we change position of entire geojson layer in map.As of now Geojson layer displaying in [0,0] coordinates.
sample geojson and displaying code

```
var geojson={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "entities",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "ELEV-FURN-MOVABLE @ 1", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference", "ExtendedEntity": "   100      1", "Linetype": "ByBlock", "EntityHandle": "A3479" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 28.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ], [ 94.906798251162414, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 94.906798251162414, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ], [ 94.906798251162414, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 94.906798251162414, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 28.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 28.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 28.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 29.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 29.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 30.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 30.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 31.90679825115512, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 31.90679825115512, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 45.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 45.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 44.906798251155131, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 44.906798251155131, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 43.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 43.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 42.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 42.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 41.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 41.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 40.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 40.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 39.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 39.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 38.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 38.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 37.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 37.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 36.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 36.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 35.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 35.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 34.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 34.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 33.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 33.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 32.906798251155124, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 32.906798251155124, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 79.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 79.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 80.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 80.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 81.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 81.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 93.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 93.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 92.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 92.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 91.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 91.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 90.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 90.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 89.906798251162414, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 89.906798251162414, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 88.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 88.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 87.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 87.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 86.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 86.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 85.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 85.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 84.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 84.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 83.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 83.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 82.9067982511624, 783.665582924625596, 0.0 ], [ 82.9067982511624, 765.665582924624914, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 48.181739517756796, 781.409011031471891, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 781.409011031471891, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 778.052665054441604, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 778.052665054441604, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 781.409011031471891, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 48.181739517756796, 776.302229679291486, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 776.302229679291486, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 772.945883702261199, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 772.945883702261199, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 776.302229679291486, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 48.181739517756796, 767.922154817778619, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 767.922154817778619, 0.0 ], [ 78.195410763022664, 771.278500794808906, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 771.278500794808906, 0.0 ], [ 48.181739517756796, 767.922154817778619, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
]}

 let layer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
          style: myStyle
        }).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Pls add you geojson code and yor code to display the layer. Normally the coordinates are in the geojson object

Comment: This should help `map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());`

Comment: Yes i tried map.fitBounds.But i want to know how to set fitBounds for that geojson layer.

Answer (score 0):

`fitBounds` is the method to which you specify layer bouds.
In your case it's called `layer`. Below is my example of geojson.

The map is set somewhere to London, after three seconds I set the center of my geojson.

```js
// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZomm: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 51.51527266031298;
const lon = -0.132200717926025;

// calling map
const map = L.map('map', config).setView([lat, lon], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "place"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            16.54541015625,
            49.724479188712984
          ],
          [
            24.01611328125,
            49.724479188712984
          ],
          [
            24.01611328125,
            53.74871079689897
          ],
          [
            16.54541015625,
            53.74871079689897
          ],
          [
            16.54541015625,
            49.724479188712984
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
}

let layer = L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
setTimeout(() => {
  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}, 3000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.Can we set center for particularly that geojson layer.For Ex. Can we move entire (geojson portion) polygon from polska to london  without changing geojson coordinates.In my scenario geojson layer always projecting in sea i want to move to land.

Comment: You must be confusing different terms.
My example centers the geojson exactly in the center of the map in Poland.
The second part of the question I do not understand shifting without change without geojson coordinates. Maybe that's what you mean [leaflet-truesize](https://wbkd.github.io/leaflet-truesize/)